# How to wrap values within % % placefolder in mysql module in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Is there any way to write some queries such as this in `mysql` module in Node.js?

```
select * from table_name where name like "%value%";
```

In Node.js, you can use `?` placeholder in order to put some values into sql query. However, the following code doesn't work.

```
connection.query('select * from table_name where name like "%?%"', value, function(err, rows){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(rows);
});
```

When I wrote the code above, I got an empty result since mysql interpreted my code as `%'value'%`, superfluous single quotation included. So is there any way to put `value` into sql query without including that extra quotation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholders are for escaping, not really for text formatting.

You can use this instead:

```
connection.query('select * from table_name where name like ?', '%' + value + '%', ...)
```